# Conditional types of nested JSON-objects

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am not too used to TypeScript and I need a more complicated type for a rather simple code. Center role is played by the following JSON-object I parsed from the web. You dont need to read all of it, but understand that every model class such as "LogisticRegression" represent different possible keys - as any of the models. Als dont mind the formatting.

```
export const MODEL = {
"LogisticRegression": {
  "penalty": {
    "default": "l2",
    "options": ["l1", "l2", "elasticnet", "none"]
  },
  "dual": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "tol": { "default": "1e-4", "options": null },
  "C": { "default": "1.0", "options": null },
  "fit_intercept": { "default": "True", "options": null },
  "intercept_scaling": { "default": "1", "options": null },
  "class_weight": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "random_state": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "solver": {
    "default": "lbfgs",
    "options": ["newton-cg", "lbfgs", "liblinear", "sag", "saga"]
  },
  "max_iter": { "default": "100", "options": null },
  "multi_class": {
    "default": "auto",
    "options": ["auto", "ovr", "multinomial"]
  },
  "verbose": { "default": "0", "options": null },
  "warm_start": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "n_jobs": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "l1_ratio": { "default": "None", "options": null }
},
"RandomForestClassifier": {
  "n_estimators": { "default": "100", "options": null },
  "criterion": {
    "default": "gini",
    "options": ["gini", "entropy", "log_loss"]
  },
  "max_depth": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "min_samples_split": { "default": "2", "options": null },
  "min_samples_leaf": { "default": "1", "options": null },
  "min_weight_fraction_leaf": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "max_features": { "default": "sqrt", "options": ["sqrt", "log2", "None"] },
  "max_leaf_nodes": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "min_impurity_decrease": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "bootstrap": { "default": "True", "options": null },
  "oob_score": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "n_jobs": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "random_state": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "verbose": { "default": "0", "options": null },
  "warm_start": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "class_weight": {
    "default": "None",
    "options": ["balanced", "balanced_subsample"]
  },
  "ccp_alpha": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "max_samples": { "default": "None", "options": null }
},
"LinearRegression": {
  "fit_intercept": { "default": "True", "options": null },
  "normalize": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "copy_X": { "default": "True", "options": null },
  "n_jobs": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "positive": { "default": "False", "options": null }
},
"SGDClassifier": {
  "loss": {
    "default": "hinge",
    "options": [
      "hinge",
      "log_loss",
      "log",
      "modified_huber",
      "squared_hinge",
      "perceptron",
      "squared_error",
      "huber",
      "epsilon_insensitive",
      "squared_epsilon_insensitive"
    ]
  }
},
"RandomForestRegressor": {
  "n_estimators": { "default": "100", "options": null },
  "criterion": {
    "default": "squared_error",
    "options": ["squared_error", "absolute_error", "poisson"]
  },
  "max_depth": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "min_samples_split": { "default": "2", "options": null },
  "min_samples_leaf": { "default": "1", "options": null },
  "min_weight_fraction_leaf": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "max_features": { "default": "1.0", "options": ["sqrt", "log2", "None"] },
  "max_leaf_nodes": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "min_impurity_decrease": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "bootstrap": { "default": "True", "options": null },
  "oob_score": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "n_jobs": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "random_state": { "default": "None", "options": null },
  "verbose": { "default": "0", "options": null },
  "warm_start": { "default": "False", "options": null },
  "ccp_alpha": { "default": "0.0", "options": null },
  "max_samples": { "default": "None", "options": null }
  }
}
```

So now take a look at the React-Component I want to use it in:

```
import React from "react";
import { MODEL } from "./modelDict";

type inputprops = keyof typeof MODEL;

function InputBlock(props: {modelname:inputprops}):JSX.Element{
    const model = MODEL[props.modelname];

    let inputList = [];
    let parameter: INEEDATYPE
    for (parameter in model){
        inputList.push(<li>{parameter}</li>)
        inputList.push(<input placeholder={model[parameter]["default"]}></input>)
}

    return(
        <>
            <h3>{props.modelname}</h3>
            <ul>
                {inputList}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export { InputBlock }
```

"inputprops" is what I want it to be: "LogisticRegression" | "RandomForestClassifier" | "LinearRegression" | "SGDClassifier" | "RandomForestRegressor"

But within the for-loop, I have no idea how to come up with a type that allows me model[parameter]["default"]. Do I need to come up with a different logic or is there a way to provide a type the way I intend?

I really appreciate an answer, because I feel this is out of reach for me without a nod in the right direction.

Best Regards

Martin

Comment: A helper type like this `type parameterType = { [key: string]: { default: string, options: string[] | null } }` should work here.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I had to make a small tweak on your solution to make it work. :) Also interesting to learn that the type of keys is string | number and not only string!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Eldar´s answer I came to the following working solution. Firstly, I explicitly stated the type of my MODEL-Dict as follows:

```
export {MODEL};

let MODEL : {[key:string]: { [key: string]: { default: string, options: 
string[] | null } }}

MODEL = {
    "LogisticRegression": {...}
    ...
}
```

The rest was rather easy with:

```
import React from "react";
import { MODEL } from "./modelDict";

type inputprops = keyof typeof MODEL;

function InputBlock(props: {modelname:inputprops}):JSX.Element{

    const model = MODEL[props.modelname];

    let inputList = [];
    let parameter: keyof typeof model
    for (parameter in model){
        inputList.push(<li>{parameter}</li>)
        inputList.push(<input placeholder={model[parameter]["default"]}> 
        </input>)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <h3>{props.modelname}</h3>
            <ul>
                {inputList}
            </ul>
        </>
    )
}

export { InputBlock }
```

I appreciate the help!